# Add event to device calendar, Added event invisible or display wrong data

Tags: android, events, kotlin, calendar

I am working with the calendar event add in background.

I can add the event successfully, but not all times.

Some times event display proper, event uri return the proper ID, but sometimes i use the intent to view that event using the same id message say's no event found. and some time display as below.

[image]

While manually open the calender and check the added event it nothing to show, sometime show only birthday event Like below

[image]

After sometime(Approx 30 to 50 sec) when i open calendar to check event again, event removed automatically. Refer snap

[image]

Code below i am using to add an event in background

```
      val llStartMillis: Long = Common.getDateTimeLong(foEventInfo.event_datetime) - Constants.DaysInMillis.HOURS
      val llEndMillis: Long = Common.getDateTimeLong(foEventInfo.event_datetime)

       Log.i(TAG, "Event start times in milli = " + llStartMillis)
       Log.i(TAG, "Event end times in milli = " + llEndMillis)

       val loContentValues = ContentValues().apply() {
           put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, llStartMillis)
           put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, llEndMillis)
           put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, foEventInfo.event_name)
           put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, foEventInfo.event_desc)
           put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3)

           Log.i(TAG, "TimeZone = " + TimeZone.getDefault().id)
           put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().id)
        }

        val uri: Uri? = getActivityContext()?.contentResolver?.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, loContentValues)

         // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
         val eventID: Long = uri?.lastPathSegment?.toLong() ?: -1
         Log.i(TAG, "Event ID = " + eventID)

         // Check event by id using an intent.
         val uriss: Uri = 
         ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID)
         val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(uriss)
         getActivityContext()!!.startActivity(intent)
```

Here `foEventInfo` is my model class and value not null.
Log display as below.

```
Event start times in milli = 1540877400000
Event end times in milli = 1540881000000
TimeZone = Asia/Kolkata
Event ID = 643
```

I have below Problems using above code.

***1. Event did not add sometimes.***

***2. Event add but remove after sometime, automatically(approx 30 sec).***

***3. Event display as birthday***

Language i use little pure as i am in confusion how to explain, so please ignore grammar.

Can any one help what was the issue with the code. its really panic now.